# Capture only same characters among the ones that are matched by a regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match all the cases in which the dot is used wrongly as follows:

*My friend is hungry .I am happy*

The goal is to obtain:

*My friend is hungry. I am happy*

How can I make this using Regex and Python?

I am able to match the right cases using:

```
r'\s\.[a-zA-Z]'
```

I want also to replace the wrong . with the correct one (I tried using re.sub, but with the previous regex it replace also the first letter of the word after the dot)

Suggestions?

Comment: You can try [this](https://regex101.com/r/dpvSvD/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is match a whitespace character and a dot and use a positive lookahead `(?=[a-zA-Z])` to assert what is on the right is a-zA-Z and replace with a dot and a space:

```
\s\.(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6CHQj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NKPLfm)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\s\.(?=[a-zA-Z])"
result = re.sub(regex, ". ", "My friend is hungry .I am happy")

if result:
    print (result) # My friend is hungry. I am happy
```

Or as [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) suggests in the comment, a more general option is:

```
\s+\.(?=\w)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c6CHQj/2)

Comment: Maybe use `\s+\.(?=\w)` as a more general pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks! That is a good suggestion. I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

test_str = "My friend is hungry .I am happy"
regex = r"\s+\." # add `(?<=\w)` for lookahead as indicated by other answer
subst = ". "

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Xg5hB7/2)